# Catalog page doesnt work when on product page

Tags: error, catalog, 404

hello i have an issue with our catalog page on this website:
http://grevegaver.dk/

if you press the "Kataloger" page it works fine on the frontpage. But if you go on to any productpage and press the "Kataloger" page it gives you an error 404 :/

I dont know why it does this and i hope some of you can help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

May be the Problem is you are using direct Kataloger url in

`<a href="kataloger" />`

use base url instead of direct Kataloger in href.

`<a href="<?php echo $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(); ?>kataloger" />`

```
http://grevegaver.dk/kataloger  -- Works Fine
http://grevegaver.dk/firmajulegaver-2017/kataloger  -- 404 Error
http://grevegaver.dk/elektronik/ure/bordure-vaegure/kataloger - 404 Error
http://grevegaver.dk/XXXX/kataloger - 404 Error
```